# Hibernate how to add a new row to a table with a foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am using Java8 with Hibernate and MySQL.

I have the following tables with a join table:

```
+-------+     +----------------+     +------------+
| job   |     |   person_job   |     |   person   | 
+-------+     +----------------+     +------------+
|  ID   |     |     PER_ID     |     |     ID     | 
|       |     |   JOB_ID (PK)  |     +------------+
+-------+     +----------------+
```

(A `PERSON` can have many `JOBs`)

When I try save a new `JOB`, it has a foreign key join to and existing `PERSON`. It looks like Hibernate wants to also save a new `PERSON`, resulting in a duplicate entry.  I thought Hibernate would be smart enough, that if there is already a matching `PERSON`, it won't try save it again.

Resulting in the following error when trying to save a row in the `JOB` table:

> ```
> MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '338-1688' for key 'PRIMARY'
> ```

**SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM ebdb.person_job;

PER_ID    JOB_ID
 338        16
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM ebdb.person

 ID
 338
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM ebdb.job;

 ID
 16
```

**Job.java**

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "person_job", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "PER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") })
private Person person;
```

When I run in debug mode, I see the new `Job` row it is trying to `merge` has an `ID` of `26` and a `PERSON` with an `ID` of `338` as expected.

```
protected T merge(T entity) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    T attached = null;
    if (entity.getId() != null) {
        attached = entityManager.find(entityClass, entity.getId());
    }
    if (attached == null) {
        attached = entityClass.newInstance();
    }

    BeanUtils.copyProperties(entity, attached);
    entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
     attached = entityManager.merge(attached);

    return attached;
}
```

**Question**

How do you create a new entry on one table (`JOB`), that has a foreign key join to an existing entry (`PERSON`)?

i.e. I want to just maintain a `@ManyToOne` relationship.

Please can anyone assist.

**UPDATE**

If I try `persist` instead of `merge`, I get:

> detached entity passed to persist: com.jobs.spring.domain.Person

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

I update with the attached object.

```
            Person attached = entityManager.find(Person.class, person.getId());
            person = attached;
            job.setPerson(person);
```